# Anorm RowParser with Stacked Case Classes

Tags: scala, anorm

I have a case class that has more than 22 elements and therefore can't be parsed using the Json Format method. Because of that I broke it up into 3 different case classes. I now have

```
case class PushMessage(stages: Stages, osData: OSData, vendorId: String, problem: Boolean,  totalStageThrees: Int, totalStageFours: Int, expectedTotals: Int, startTime: Long,
                       date: Long, topics: String, latestUpdate: Long)
case class Stages(stageOne: Boolean, stageTwo: Boolean, stageThree: Boolean, stageFour: Boolean, stageFive: Boolean, highestStage: Int)
case class OSData(iOSTotal: Int, androidTotal: Int, iOSRunningCount: Int, androidRunningCount: Int, iOSFailures: Int, androidFailures: Int, iOSComplete: Boolean,
                  androidComplete: Boolean)
```

However, when I try to parse some SQL and convert it to a PushMessage using RowParser, it says that it

> cannot find anorm.Column[data.Stages] for stages in constructor PushMessage

I have Macros as:

```
implicit val stagesParser: RowParser[Stages] = Macro.namedParser[Stages]
implicit val osDataParser: RowParser[OSData] = Macro.namedParser[OSData]
implicit val pushParser: RowParser[PushMessage] = Macro.namedParser[PushMessage]
```

But, that doesn't seem to work. How can I parse this simply in Anorm? Or, is there simply no way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check your Anorm version, just trying it, I don't get any error.

Comment: I'm using 2.5.0. Is there a later version?

Comment: Yes, 2.5.0 is more than 1year old. Check 2.5.2: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.typesafe.play%22%20AND%20a%3A%22anorm_2.11%22

Comment: Awesome. That was it. Thanks so much.